# Cleaner way of getting date out of pandas timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Suppose I have a df like so:

```
foo = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'a': [1, 2, 3],
        'b': ['2021-01-05 05:15', '2021-01-06 11:10', '2021-03-01 09:00']
    }
)
```

And I want to convert column `b` to datetime and extract only the date part. I can do something like:

```
foo['date'] = pd.to_datetime(foo.b).dt.date
```

But even though this returns a Numpy array of datetime objects, Pandas doesn't recognise this and assigns an `object` dtype to the column:

```
foo.dtypes

Out: 
a        int64
b       object
date    object
dtype: object
```

I can of course get it to be a datetime by casting it to datetime again:

```
foo['date'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.to_datetime(foo.b).dt.date)
```

I can also get it with string slicing

```
foo['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(foo.b.str[:11])
```

But I feel like there must be a cleaner way of getting a date out of datetime column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html):

```
foo['date'] = pd.to_datetime(foo['b']).dt.normalize()
```

Output:

```
>>> foo
   a                 b       date
0  1  2021-01-05 05:15 2021-01-05
1  2  2021-01-06 11:10 2021-01-06
2  3  2021-03-01 09:00 2021-03-01

>>> foo.dtypes
a                int64
b               object
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

However your last solution is a good solution `pd.to_datetime(foo.b.str[:11])`.